# Java Swing JOptionPane Button Options

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So this is my first time working with the JOptionPane and I was wondering if someone could help explain how I could make both of my buttons do certain actions? For all intent and purposes have it just print out "Hi". Here is my code. So far it only prints out "Hi" if I click the "Uhh...." button but I want it to do the same when I click the "w00t!!" button as well. I know it has something to do with the parameter "JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION" but I'm not sure what exactly I have to do with it. Thanks for the help in advance!

```
Object[] options = {"Uhh....", "w00t!!"};
int selection = winnerPopup.showOptionDialog(null,
    "You got within 8 steps of the goal! You win!!",
    "Congratulations!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
    options, options[0]);
    if(selection == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)
    {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html),

> When one of the showXxxDialog methods returns an integer, the
>   possible values are:
>
> ```
> YES_OPTION
> NO_OPTION
> CANCEL_OPTION
> OK_OPTION
> CLOSED_OPTION
> ```

So, your code should look something like,

```
if(selection == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
else if(selection == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
    System.out.println("wOOt!!");
}
```

But regardless, this logic is a bit bizarre so I would probably just roll my own dialog.

Comment: Yeah I was reading that from the docs, but how come there is only one parameter in the showXxxDialog methods that deals with all the OPTIONs?

Comment: @Mike, that's a separate question altogether.

Comment: @Mike, For more information, please see [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Answer (score 0):

In JOPtionPane class there are some constants that represent the values ​​of the buttons.

```
 /** Return value from class method if YES is chosen. */
    public static final int         YES_OPTION = 0;
    /** Return value from class method if NO is chosen. */
    public static final int         NO_OPTION = 1;
    /** Return value from class method if CANCEL is chosen. */
    public static final int         CANCEL_OPTION = 2;
```

You changed the names of the buttons, and consequently, your first button "Uhh" has the value 0, and its button "w00t!" assumed a value of 1.

So, you can use this:

```
if(selection == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
{
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
else if(selection == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
    // do stuff
}
```

or maybe could be better use the swicht/case function:

```
    switch (selection )
    {
        case 0:
        {

            break;
        }
        case 1:
        {

            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: in your switch statement, why not use the `JOptionPane` constants in the `case` statements?

Comment: How has changed the name of the buttons, the correct would create new constants in own class and hence new values​​. So could use them on the switch. Like: 

private static final int Uhh = 0; private static final int wOOt = 1;

Comment: If you have it Object[] options = {"Uhh ....", "w00t!", "TEST", "ABC"}, what do you do?

Comment: You should use named constants in the switch statement. Update your answer and I'll remove my down vote.

Answer (score -3):

```
int selection = 0;
JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
            "You got within 8 steps of the goal! You win!!",
            "Congratulations!", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null,
            options, options[0]);

if(selection == JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION)
{
    System.out.println("Hi");
}
```